# How to Update from windows phone 8 to windows phone 8.1 in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have installed visual studio 2013 with windows phone target os version 8.but i need windows phone target os version 8.1 ,i installed windows 8.1 updates sdk toolkit and vs2013.4 was installed but could not opened

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest Visual Studio 2013 update. Currently: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44921)

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual studio 2015,This is the latest one for creating windows universal app, You have to use anything